# Download output of aspose API PDF to EPUB conversion in python

Tags: python, pdf, epub, aspose

I have been using the cloud below and it has produced no errors yet there is also no outputted epub file. Am I missing something? Can someone please explain?

```py
import asposewordscloud
from asposewordscloud.apis.words_api import WordsApi

words_api = WordsApi(client_id = ‘SECRET, client_secret = ‘SECRET’)
doc = open(‘Input.pdf’, 'rb')
request = asposewordscloud.models.requests.ConvertDocumentRequest(document=doc, format='epub')
convert = words_api.convert_document(request)
```

I tried the above code and was expected a sign or something to show me that it has actually worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the convert_document API method returns an output file in response, so you need to save the output from the response as follows:

### Python convert PDF to EPUB

```py
# For complete examples and data files, please go to https://github.com/aspose-words-cloud/aspose-words-cloud-python
# Import module
import asposewordscloud
import asposewordscloud.models.requests
#from shutil import copyfile

# Please get your Client ID and Secret from https://dashboard.aspose.cloud.
client_id='xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx'
client_secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

words_api = asposewordscloud.WordsApi(client_id,client_secret)
inputFileName = 'C:/Temp/02_pages.pdf'
outputFileName = 'C:/Temp/output.epub'

#Convert PDF to EPUB
request = asposewordscloud.models.requests.ConvertDocumentRequest(document=open(inputFileName, 'rb'), format='epub')
result = words_api.convert_document(request)

#Save output to local drive
open(outputFileName,'wb').write(result)
#copyfile(result, outputFileName)
#print("Result {}".format(result))
```

P.S: I am a developer evangelist at aspose.cloud.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. If you want, I can send you the finished project when am I finished via my github.

Comment: Yes, you can share the link of your project; it may help some other community member.